# Managing security in mvc3 using FormsAuthentication method

Tags: razor, forms-authentication

I am using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`.It works fine but when I use same method in another project with different database and execute both projects at same time I get following problem:

1.When I log on the first project it auto logs On with same username in the second one although other database does not contains the username.

Is there any way to solve this Or should I use another method such as FormsAuthenticationTicket or Sessions.Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was with same cookie name.When two web applications are deployed in the same domain then when anyone is logged in then the second one will be automatically logged in both application because they use the same Authentication's cookie name.
So finally I ended changing the cookie name in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MynewCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false"/>
</authentication>
```